# How to write and retrieve the sqlite data into the file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Friend it just general question .

How can write and retrieve the data on to the file .And how can  make this file   in **.csv** format.

For example i am retrieve data like that

```
NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f\n",longitude,latitude] autorelease];
[locations addObject:coords];
```

Than how can write this data on to the file in **.csv format**.

And than How can i retrieve this data

Comment: is there specific need to use csv format, you can convert it into sqlite database and then you can work on sqlite...

Comment: No there is specific to use .csv formate .I just want to write the data on to file which has the csv fromat .And retrieve that

Comment: I have answered, do you want to have read/write from/to csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write csv

```
NSString *coords = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f,%f\n",longitude,latitude] autorelease];

NSData *csvData =  [coords dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *UsrDocPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DocsDir = [UsrDocPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *csvPath = [DocsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"coords.csv"];

    //This is upto your logic that do you want to remove existant csv file or not
    BOOL success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:csvPath];
    if(success){
        [FileManager removeItemAtPath:csvPath error:&error];
    }

    [csvData writeToFile:csvPath atomically:YES];
```

To read from file

```
NSData *csvData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:csvPath];
NSString *strCSV = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:csvData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There is a csv parser written by dave delong. you can use that.

Comment: I don't want csv parser i need that i data write down on file and read that file only

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll want to make sure that you're using [FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to access the database, because people who use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C are masochists. You can do that like this:

```
FMDatabase *db = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:@"/path/to/db/file"];
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM tableName"];
while([results nextRow]) {
  NSDictionary *resultRow = [results resultDict];
  NSArray *orderedKeys = [[resultRow allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
  //iterate over the dictionary
}
```

As for writing to a CSV file, well there's code for that too:

```
#import "CHCSV.h"

CHCSVWriter * csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:@"/path/to/csv/file" atomic:NO];

//write stuff
[csvWriter closeFile];
[csvWriter release];
And to combine them, you'd do:

FMDatabase *db = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:@"/path/to/db/file"];
if (![db open]) {
  //couldn't open the database
  [db release];
  return nil;
}
FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM tableName"];
CHCSVWriter *csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:@"/path/to/csv/file" atomic:NO];
while([results nextRow]) {
  NSDictionary *resultRow = [results resultDict];
  NSArray *orderedKeys = [[resultRow allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
  //iterate over the dictionary
  for (NSString *columnName in orderedKeys) {
    id value = [resultRow objectForKey:columnName];
    [csvWriter writeField:value];
  }
  [csvWriter writeLine];
}
[csvWriter closeFile];
[csvWriter release];

[db close];
[db release];
```

That will write the contents of the tableName table out to a CSV file.

Then you can use CSV Parser to parse the CSV and get data.

Comment: I am confused .Can you explain in better way please

Comment: Shima, Above code is for fetch the data from db and then write it in to file .CSV. After writing when ever you want to read data from CSV you need to use CSV parser.